# Designing show/hide flow for admin

Tags: lists, selection, grid

Running into a UX problem on a webpage I'm designing.

The flow is than an administrator of a company can select what items to show/hide to a member.

So he will have access to a list of all items and if the user he is editing can see them or not.

The first thought was to have a grid with item names in col 1 and checkboxes in col 2 with the title " Show" and a checkbox in each row.

However this does not seem intuitive and how do you phrase the column so its easy to understand that you are showing / hiding the item for the user.

edit:
Worth noting is that it might be more options later, like show but lock item. etc.

Comment: Duplicate?
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46613/permissions-and-roles

Answer (score 3):

If there's just an option(for the visibility state) **it's okay to have checkboxes**, since it's a well known control for the users which keeps confusion to the minimum.

Alternatively and depending who are the target users and what else might be added in the future you could use a  similar approach to the ones in Image Editing applications, where each **binary state control explains itself with an icon**, which are more expressive than checkboxes. Also u**sers won't need to remember what attribute match what column**. 
 I made a mockup as an example:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdolCP.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: And a nice tooltip-text for each Image, so on Mouseover I can read what exactly this control does! "Hide Item3 from View for all users"

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem I happened to face it some time ago.
the solution I addoperato I was the one on the list with multiple columns.

Each row and each column was a user his property.
All that he has had an on-off toggle.

This solution, however, was fine because the settings were changed a few.
If you have many ipostazioni it should structure the list-detail. This way you can make more room in all your options and make clear the actions.

A search bar for user then obviously facilitate the user in finding precisely users