# Where to put a search filter checkbox left or right side?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-expectation, e-commerce, position

I have a search filters design for an eCommerce website, I wonder where should I put the checkbox of each filter? Any suggestion in terms of the usability and user experience?

[image]

Comment: In LTR languages, put the check box left to the text. In [RTL languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left), put it on the right side.

Comment: more answers in this UX question [https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5080/should-checkbox-labels-be-to-the-right-or-the-left]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there's no hard and fast rule for matters like this, option 1 has the advantage of keeping the checkbox closer to the item it relates to, preventing the user from needing to mentally process which checkbox belongs to which item. In fact, I'd reduce the gap between the checkboxes and their labels quite significantly if I were you.

It also helps conceptually to handle scenarios where an item may wrap due to very long content, since on the left (in LTR languages) the checkbox can align directly with the start of each item in the list (like a bullet in an unordered list); if you imagine a label wrapping in option 2, it's not clear to me how I'd expect the checkbox to be aligned vertically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Initially, the option 1 was my design and after receiving a few feedback from the marketing(They are allowed to provide the input), they prefer the checkbox on the right side. But, as you mentioned, considering the fact that the label wrapping to the next line and the verticle alignment issue, the option 1 is better than option 2.